# How to convert a function's parameters into an interface with named properties derived from the function param names?

Tags: typescript

I have a function (imported from an external library) that looks like this:

```
const fn = (s: string, n: number) => null;
```

I want to be able to call it like this (to make the parameters more explicit):

`fn1({s:'string', n:1})`

So far this is the best I've been able to come up:

```
type FnParams = Parameters<typeof fn>;

interface FnParamsObjectForm {
    s: FnParams [0];
    n: FnParams [1];
}

const fn2 = ({s, n}: FnParamsObjectForm )=>fn(s,n);
```

is there some way to do this without this step (the manual mapping from tuple=>interface with name properties):

```
interface FnParamsObjectForm {
    s: p[0];
    n: p[1];
}
```

and map the names of the parameters in the original function to their type in an interface?

Comment: According to this discussion, it does not appear to be possible: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26019#issuecomment-568236218

Comment: I may be reading this wrong but you can declare the function like this ```const fn = ({s, n}:{s: string, n: number}) => null;```

Comment: @Greg looks like I'm not the only one that wants this. Thanks for digging this up!

Comment: @mpc75 if I were the one defining the function I would do that but it's imported from an external library. I'm looking for a generalized way to map a function accepting multiple  parameters to a fn accepting a single object parameter where the properties have the names of the params in the original function.